# Pylance <reportMissingModuleSource> on editable python package inside a VSCode DevContainer

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

Following [Setting up Matplotlib for development](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/devel/development_setup.html#installing-for-devs) I created (on Windows 11 Pro 23H2) a VSCode (v.1.86.2) DevContainer (Docker Desktop v.4.27.2):

`devcontainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "matplotlib_dev",    
        "build": {
            "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile"
        },
        "customizations": {
            "vscode": {
                "extensions": [
                    "ms-python.debugpy"
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

where `Dockerfile` take care of (almost) all the steps described in the link above :

```
FROM bitnami/python:3.11.4-debian-11-r2
WORKDIR /app
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git
RUN cd &&\
    pip install --upgrade pip &&\
    pip install -r /app/matplotlib/requirements/dev/dev-requirements.txt &&\
    pip install meson-python ninja pybind11 &&\
    cd /app/matplotlib/ && python -m pip install --verbose --no-build-isolation --editable ".[dev]"
```

at this point `pip list` shows correctly:
`matplotlib3.9.0.dev0    /app/matplotlib`

on `settings.json` I set:

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "/app/matplotlib"
    ],
    "python.analysis.logLevel": "Trace"
}
```

so now, with my `foo.py` :

```
import matplotlib as mpl 
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    print(f'matplotlib file : {mpl.__file__}')
```

I checked the installation (CRTL+F5 run without debugging), and It pass :

`matplotlib file : /app/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py`

but I don't understand how to fix the Pylance error : **reportMissingModuleSource**

Has anyone experienced the same problem and solved it to use such a DevContainer to contribute in any python open-source project ?